# "Shepherding" vs. "sheepherding"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *shepherding* and *sheepherding* (sheep herding?)?

What is the difference between *shepherd* and *sheepherder*?

I had only heard *shepherd* until I found *sheepherder* on a [page on the California minimum wage](http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/faq_minimumwage.htm).

Comment: It's "sheepherder", not "sheephearder".

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Editing grammar takes on a whole new meaning here compared to the other SE sites! :)

Comment: @Peter - unless it's a person hired to listen to sheep baa !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between a shepherd and a sheepherder?

*Sheep-herder* is *a person who herds sheep in large numbers in unfenced country.* It is a word used in the USA.
A *shepherd* is *a person employed to guard, tend, and herd sheep, especially at pasture; a member of a pastoral people herding and usually owning sheep, etc*. *Sheperd* can also be used in figurative sense as in the following sentence.

> Then the shepherd read, explaining a portion of Scripture.

Comment: *Shepherd* is also the verb, with both meanings: *to tend as a shepherd* and *to guide or guard in the manner of a shepherd - "shepherded the bill through Congress"* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shepherd)

Answer (score 3):

Shepherding is also widely used in a general sense of guiding, helping or looking after. "He shepherded his grandmother through the process of upgrading her PC."

"Sheepherding" is strictly managing actual sheep.

Comment: Well, I never heard "so and so shepherded him to do so and so" sentence, thats for sure....

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog: That usage is fairly poetic or archaic and not used often, but it is a valid metaphor. It is used a lot in the Bible, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Sheep Herder rounds up the sheep and walks behind them to move them.  A Shepherd walks in front of the sheep and they follow him.

Comment: This article seems to agree. https://www.lds.org/new-era/1977/06/sheep-shepherds-and-sheepherders?lang=eng

Comment: Not really true. In the UK most people who work with sheep drive them either using one or more dogs controlled by calls and whistles or they drive them themselves. However British English doesn't have the term 'sheepherder', people who work with sheep in the UK are either 'shepherds' or 'sheep farmers', usually shepherds. As someone who was brought up in a sheep farming area and in a Christian family I only knew of the concept of a shepherd leading sheep from the Bible.

Answer (score 1):

I checked up dictionaries, and here are the results:
**herder** – a person who looks after a herd of livestock or makes a living from keeping livestock, especially in open country.
‘they are nomadic cattle herders by tradition’  {https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/herder    2019.04.16}
**shepherd** – 1. A person who tends and rears sheep. 1.1 A member of the clergy who provides spiritual care and guidance for a congregation. {ibidem}
**shepherd** – someone whose job is to take care of sheep {Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, CD}
**sheepherder** - shepherd (def. 1).
[1870–75, Amer.; SHEEP + HERDER]   {Random House Webster’s Unabridged Doctionary, CD}
**shepherd** – 1. a person who herds, tends, and guards sheep. {ibidem}
And as far as the comment to James' answer - the article deals with religious matters. With all due respect, it does not seem to be a reliable source to support the linguistic discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers to this question have asserted (without offering any supporting documentation) that the difference between a shepherd and a sheepherder is that a shepherd has the sheep's trust and therefore leads the flock, walking in front of them, but a sheepherder has no such relationship to the sheep and therefore controls the flock by driving them from behind.

I was curious about this explanation because it suggests a kind of convenient metaphorical explanation of how a religious person should act as pastor to a flock of believers. Indeed, the linked article that NVZ cites in a comment beneath James's answer on August 28, 2016, in corroboration of James's assertion is a lengthy discourse on religious duty framed as a kind of extended parable contrasting the behavior of a true shepherd and the behavior of a mere sheepherder. From James Moss, "[Sheep, Shepherds, and Sheepherders](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/new-era/1977/06/sheep-shepherds-and-sheepherders?lang=eng)" (June 1977) on the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints website:

> For whether you know it or not, you are either a **shepherd** or a **sheepherder**. Want to know why, and what the difference is?
>
> A few years ago, Elder Thomas S. Monson contrasted two experiences:
>
> > “One thing I remember best about Provo Canyon [in Utah] is the experience encountered when driving around a bend near Vivian Park—to meet on the road a large herd of sheep. Have you ever seen a **sheepherder** in one of our western mountain canyons directing the sheep? He is usually at the rear of the flock, slouched down on his horse, sound asleep. And doing the work are half a dozen small dogs yapping and barking at the heels of the sheep. He is a **sheepherder**.
> >
> > “A few months ago in Munich, Germany, I saw a true **shepherd**. There he was with staff in hand, singing, walking in front of his flock; and the flock followed behind him. When he turned to the left, the sheep turned to the left; when he went to the right, they went to the right. There were no dogs barking at the heels of his sheep. They indeed knew their **shepherd** and were following the pathway he took.” (Pathways to Perfection, p. 93.)
>
> Now, what was the difference between the **shepherd** and the **sheepherder**? It was leadership! And how does that difference apply, and why is it so important to you? Because you, my friend, are a leader!

Moss's argument is essentially *shepherd* = trusted leader, *sheepherder* = lazy follower. How does that distinction bear up in the historical record—and more particularly, how far back does it go? To judge from my research, not terribly far.

---

***The emergence of 'sheepherder' as an equivalent to 'shepherd'***

Roy Coperud, [*Words on Paper: A Manual of Prose Style for Professional Writers, Reporters, Authors, Editors, Publishers, and Teachers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PQA1AAAAMAAJ&q=%22sheepherder%22+%22shepherd%22&dq=%22sheepherder%22+%22shepherd%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ0q6CmZDlAhWEHDQIHXObCpEQ6AEwBXoECAQQAw) (1960):

> **shepherd.** Don't ask why, but in the sheep-raising areas of the West the man who tends the flocks is not a *shepherd*, but the comparatively clumsy variant, *sheepherder*. *Shepherd*, for some mysterious reason, seems on the way to becoming literary.

The identical entry appears in Copperud's subsequent book *American Usage and Style: The Consensus* (1980).

David North & Jennifer Wagner, [*Nonimmigrant Workers in the U.S.: Current Trends and Future Implications*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aF4PAAAAYAAJ&q=%22sheepherder%22+shepherd&dq=%22sheepherder%22+shepherd&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj__cXLwZDlAhVxNX0KHVQ2DDIQ6AEwCHoECAgQAw) (1980) concurs with Copperud:

> The **sheepherder** (**shepherd** appears to have become obsolete) stays with the animals, cooks his own meals, and lives in a small trailer (if he is lucky) or a tent. There may be little human contact beyond a delivery every week or so of a fresh batch of food.

Winifred Kupper, [*The Golden Hoof: The Story of the Sheep of the Southwest*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DPsYAAAAIAAJ&q=%22sheepherder%22+%22shepherd%22&dq=%22sheepherder%22+%22shepherd%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ0q6CmZDlAhWEHDQIHXObCpEQ6AEwBHoECAEQAw) (1945) [combined snippets] shows considerable interest in distinguishing between shepherds and sheepherders, but her focus is not between leading and following, but between Old World and New World (and in particular the West of the New World):

> In the Southwest there are no **shepherds**. The man who tends the sheep is a **sheepherder**. In the early Southwest, however, there was but one tender of sheep to whom the term "**sheepherder**" could apply: the Anglo newcomer. The Mexican, Indian, or Spanish Colonial was entitled to the more distinguishing term *pastor*.
>
> In the new West the word was hardly ever used by itself. It was nearly always preceded by one or more descriptive adjectives. "Lo, behold, the gentle **shepherd** cometh," the people of the Old World said when they saw the **shepherd** and his flock appearing over the hills in the sunset glow. But in the western world it was: "Well, look at that lousy **sheepherding** scoundrel coming over the divide with his damned sheep. Boys, get your black masks and the wagon spokes."
>
> Maybe it was this difference in attitude that caused the difference between the personalities of the **shepherd** and the **sheepherder**. The **shepherd**, because he aroused no animosity, was a somewhat colorless character at best, a gentle tender of flocks, a singer of songs, a lowly, humble servitor, the embodiment of all that was serene in pastoral life, literature, and painting. Not so his American brother. He couldn't have led a quiet, idyllic life if he had wanted to. His life was virile, adventurous, and full of obstacles, and he developed a character entirely unlike that of the Old World **shepherd**. "For God's sake," Robert Maudslay used to admonish me, "don't picture a **sheepherder** with a long-handled crook and a face like Jesus Christ. And don't give him so few as a dozen sheep crowding close to him and licking his hand. Give him a sizable flock of at least two thousand, and let them keep at a respectful distance. He was a **sheepherder**, not a **shepherd**."
>
> The Old World **shepherd**, like the *pastor* of Old Mexico, remained a **shepherd** all his life, which probably accounts for  the vast amount of literature devoted to him. The **sheepherder**, on the other hand, was nearly always a potential sheepman and often a potential millionaire. That is why one often hears the **sheepherder** of the early Southwest referred to as a sheepman; it is also one of the reasons why a sheepman, no matter how affluent, was often called "an old shepherder." In any discussion of the Anglo sheepherder the two terms may be used interchangeably.  **Sheepherders** in the Southwest lived to be presidents of banks, philanthropists, and lords of great holdings. More sheep fortunes were built by **sheepherders** than cattle fortunes by cowboys, and the difference in the two occupations had a lot to do with this fact. A man who worked with sheep was likely to develop, if he didn't already have it, a dogged persistence and responsibility.

Kupper thus presents very nearly the opposite distinction between shepherds and sheepherders that Moss does 32 years later: Old World shepherds are sedentary, amiable, unambitious, small-scale, and viewed by their neighbors as virtually part of the landscape; New World sheepherders are mobile, persistent, enterprising, and resilient in the face of hostile neighbors who view them as dangerous interlopers. For Kupper, shepherds spend a lifetime passively overseeing a small flock of sheep, whereas sheepherders actively supervise the rapid growth of a large flock and hope some day to turn their success into a job as president of a bank. The lead/follow distinction is nowhere to be found in Kupper's discussion.

The emergence of *sheepherder* as a New World term is noted without pleasure in "[A Flock of Wool](https://books.google.com/books?id=72WEdSmTI9kC&pg=PA141&dq=%22sheepherder%22+shepherd&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXtdGruZDlAhW1KH0KHU12Di8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22sheepherder%22%20shepherd&f=false)," in *The Overland Monthly* (February 1870):

> It has been reserved for California—which has vulgarized *dairy* into "milk-ranch" and ***shepherd*** into "**sheepherder**"—to make the latter less respected than any other man, save John Chinaman.

Robert Milne, "[Shepherds and Sheep-herding](https://books.google.com/books?id=wmJZAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA225&dq=sheepherder+of+fact+and+the+shepherd+of+romance&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLlo6p05DlAhU3GTQIHSPeCpoQ6AEwAHoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=sheep-herder&f=false)," in *The Californian* (March 1880) makes a similar observation about the emergence of *sheep-herder*:

> The life of a **shepherd**—or **sheep-herder** in the vernacular—in California is no sinecure. The Virgilian pastorals and the idyls of Arcady, romantic with gallant Corydons and neat-handed Phyllises, do not "pan out" well on California ranches.

---

***The 'leading shepherd, following sheepherder' thesis in print***

Th distinction that informs Moss's discussion of shepherds and sheepherders—to the great advantage of shepherds—recurs in another LDS publication. From "[The Principle of Shepherding](https://books.google.com/books?id=CfXqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sheepherder%22+shepherd&dq=%22sheepherder%22+shepherd&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpt5KtvZDlAhU-HDQIHcy1CaA4ChDoATACegQIAhAD)," in *Ensign: The Ensign of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints*, volume 26 (1996) [combined snippets]:

> "I will never forget as a young man hearing a talk about the difference between a **shepherd** and a **sheepherder**," remembers Jerry Cronin, stake mission president. "I don't remember who gave the talk or even where I was, but I can clearly recall understanding that a **sheepherder** is one who is hired for wages to watch over the sheep. He doesn't necessarily have any feelings for the sheep at all. He puts his time in and goes home.
>
> "A **shepherd**, on the other hand, has deep love, compassion, and concern for his sheep. He knows each one of them by name. Since that time I have always remembered that Christ was a **shepherd**, not a **sheepherder**.

Where did this notion of shepherds leading and sheepherders following come from? The first part, at any rate, may be biblical. From "[Love for Animals](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2010218519/1910-07-23/ed-1/seq-2/#words=shepherd%2Bsheepherder%2BShepherd%2Bsheepherder)," in the [Salt Lake City, Utah] *Goodwin's Weekly* (July 23, 1910):

> But he [Lord Althorp] states a case of real affection, as follows: "**Shepherds**, when apparently doing nothing, are studying their sheep, as any on may find who enters into conversation with them. It means actual appreciation of each individual in a flock of 500 to 1,000." That is all right, only the number is too large. That thought does not apply to the modern **sheepherder**. The relation that the real **shepherd** bears to his flock comes down to us through three thousand years of history.
>
> Of the **shepherd** the Master said: "And the sheep hear his voice, and he calleth his own sheep by name and leadeth them out. He goeth before them and the sheep follow him, for they know his voice. And a stranger they will not follow, but will flee from him for they know not his voice. The good **shepherd** layeth down his life for his sheep; the hireling fleeth because he is a hireling."
>
> ...
>
> The lady who, some years ago, lectured here on the Holy Land made the matter more clear. She said the flocks in Judea number only from 20 to 30 sheep, that each sheep has its own name and will come at the **shepherd**'s call.

The quotation in the middle of this excerpt is roughly taken from the Gospel of John 10: 3–15. It thus appears that the detail that Jesus mentions in the parable of the Good Shepherd involving the shepherd leading his willing flock homeward became a focal point for subsequent speakers of ovine parables to use in distinguishing the good caretaker (a shepherd who knows his flock and leads from the front) from a bad one (in Jesus's parable, a hireling; but in later writers' accounts, a sheepherder who doesn't know his sheep individually, who makes the dogs do all the hard work, and who drives the flock from behind.

According to the Library of Congress [descriptive blurb](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2010218519/) about *Goodwin's Weekly*, the newspaper's editor, Charles Carroll Goodwin, "also wrote poetry, stories, essays, and speeches, expounding on favorite topics such as Mormonism’s theological quirks."

I haven't been able to confirm this point, but it seems very likely that Goodwin was himself a member of the Church of Latter Day Saints, which contributes to an interesting thread of LDS continuity that extends from this 1910 discussion of shepherds and sheepherders through the one that appeared in 1977 and on to the one that appeared in 1996.

One fairly early iteration of the leading/following thesis appears in "[Sheepherder and Shepherd](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=HR19300110.2.11&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-shepherd+sheepherder-------)," in the *[Monterey, Virginia] Recorder* (January 10, 1930):

> It is necessary to differentiate between the **sheepherder** of fact and the **shepherd** of romance. The latter is a gay and poetic figure, the former anything but. The **shepherd** leads his flock with a song, the **herder** follows his with profanity. The **shepherd** reclines on a mossy bank beneath a green tree and carols a roundelay. The **herder** looks carefully about to make sure he won’t sit on a cactus, eases his wearied limbs to the unshaded hillside, and gives his vocal organs a well-earned rest.—From "Sheep" by Archer B. Gilliam.

I'm not sure how seriously to take this account of leading and following, as the description seems to be aiming for maximum humor in emphasizing contrasting imagined behavior. In any event, none of the early accounts of sheepherders describe them as differing in behavior from contemporaneous shepherds; rather they indicate that *sheepherder* is simply the modern term used for *shepherd* in the U.S. West, and then they may or may not contrast how modern sheepherders work with how the shepherd of olden times did.

---

***Conclusions***

There is zero evidence that *sheepherder* meant something different from *shepherd* in its earliest days of use in the U.S. West. Writers noting the usage in California in 1870 and in 1880 note the equivalence in meaning and characterize *sheepherder* as a vulgarization or a vernacular version of the same basic term. Subsequent writers have reached the same conclusion, although some have noted that sheepherders in the U.S. West and shepherds in the Old World operated in significantly different environments and performed significantly different tasks as part of their work.

The idea that a shepherd leads a willing, trusting flock but a sheepherder drives an unwilling, distrustful arguably appears as early as 1930 (in a context without religious overtones). The narrower idea that a flock follows its shepherd willingly appears in the Gospel of John and was parlayed in 1910 into a a half-religious/half-agricultural thesis about the difference between the real shepherd of old and the sheepherder of today (or rather, of 1910). But this thesis did not (in 1910) argue that sheepherders are indolent or that they drive their flocks from behind—it didn't address those issues at all.

The earliest instance I could find containing a fully developed contrast between loving, selfless, loyal, front-leading shepherds and lazy, in-it-for-the-money, look-out-for-number-one push-from-behind sheepherders was the instance cited by commenter NVZ from 1977—more than a century after *sheepherder* became a common alternative term for *shepherd* in the U.S. West. The two instances of this fully developed contrast that I found—one from 1977 and one from 1996—occurred within a particular religious denomination and possess instructive religious overtones. Both of these particulars suggest to me that the distinction articulated in those sources arose in that particular milieu rather than in popular usage in the wild.

As far as I've been able to determine, there is no widespread understanding outside the LDS church that shepherds and sheepherders differ in the ways that James Moss and the 1996 *Ensign* writer say they do. It is nonetheless quite striking that both James (posting in August 2016) and user363976 (posting earlier today) have provided answers making essentially the same argument that Moss and *Ensign* make. Evidently, that asserted difference between *shepherds* and *sheepherders* remains persuasive to some English speakers.

Comment: I'm not too sure that the LDS/Moss speech is helpful. The man is neither sheep-herder nor shepherd, and from what he says, he has little acquaintance with sheep (in the literal sense). All Judeo-Christian references to caring for sheep end up with a word in Aramaic or Ancient Hebrew and a culture and economic system that is far from our own.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience a shepherd is an adult chaperone of a church youth event, and a sheepherder is a professional wrestler also sometimes called a bushwhacker, and neither of them has anything to do with sheep (joke answer).